# Blazor: handling `.html` URL with page

Tags: .net, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have a simple project created with `blazorwasm --hosted`. It is going to replace an old MVC project and needs to serve a URL ended in .html.

As far as I know, this is considered a static file, so I can put it in `wwwroot`. Quick solution, but not the best one, since I have to repeat all the code on `index.html`.

I have created a page `Pages/Example.razor` to serve the .html page.

```html
@page "/Example"

<p>Some example text.</p>
```

It works when requested `/Example`, but doesn't with `/Example.html`.

My Program.cs looks like this:

```cs
using Project.Client;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Hosting;

var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my previous method below doesn't seem to work, you can always setup `.html` files to the correct location in your `wwwroot` folder and then redirect to a Razor page. An annoying task for a website with many pages, but if there's not too many then it shouldn't be an impossible task.

Say you're redirecting from `<domain>/Example/Example.html` to `<domain>/Example`, you would add a `Example.html` file in the `Example` folder in your `wwwroot`. To redirect, you can use the `<meta>` tag with `http-equiv="refresh"`.

To demonstrate, this `wwwroot/Example/Example.html` file

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" http-equiv="Refresh" content="0; url='/Example'">
    <title>Example</title>
</head>
</html>
```

would redirect the user to whatever link is provided in the `url=''`, so `/Example` in this case.

Then in your `Example.razor` file, you would add a `@page "/Example` tag at the start.

---

Unless I'm mistaken, is it not possible to just set the `@page` directive from `"/Example"` to `"/Example.html"`? Additionally, you can even have both!

```html
@page "/Example"
@page "/Example.html"

<p>Some Example Text..</p>
```

[Here's a link to Microsoft's explanation of `@page` directives](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/fundamentals/routing?view=aspnetcore-7.0)

Comment: I have tried this, but results in a `404` when browsing to `/Example.html`.

Comment: @svex99 Just added another (possible) fix to the answer, which I've tested and should work, although a bit tedious.

Comment: The first answer should have worked, for a `Pages/Example.razor` component/page. That 404 should be investigated.

Comment: Yeah that's fair, but just in case it's really needed the new one can be used

Comment: Not sure where to look at if the first method should have worked. I tried it before posting the question, and then when proposed as a solution, both times I got a white screen. When I opened debug tools showed a 404 on the request.